# Rutas CSS Plantilla Laravel

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, rutas

Estoy sigueindo un ejemplo de ejercicio de `Laravel`y quisiera saber si puedo transformar esto:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/override.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/app.css">
```

En algo parecido a estas que tengo yo de otro ejercicio:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('plugins/bootstrap3/dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
```

Intente esto:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

Quiero hacer un cambio parecido ya que obtengo este error en la depuradora de CSS:

```
GET http://laravel/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El helper `asset()` apunta al public de tu proyecto por default, intenta quitando el public ya que deseas acceder es a `css/bootstrap.min.css` dentro de la carpeta public.

Comment: Como dice el compañero: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">